# Which is the best approach to migrate DateFlows after NiFi Upgraded?

Tags: apache-nifi, dataflow

As the title suggests,after Nifi-1.9.2 was upgraded to Nifi-1.10.0,i found there are three approaches to migrate DFs are as follows:

1.Using template

2.Importing DF from Nifi registry

3.Loading the copied flow.xml.gz file from old version

WHICH IS THE BEST APPROACH?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just upgraded your NiFi from 1.9.2 to 1.10.0, loading the old flow.xml.gz would be enough. It would upgrade your flow.xml.gz too.
It always a good thing to take a look at the [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance) too though.

Comment: THANKS!I wanna know why?

Comment: BTW,i am not sure whether upgrading NiFi from 1.9.2 to 1.10.0 can refer official document about upgrading from 1.x.0 to 1.x.0.THANKS

Comment: It's containing a y relevant info about upgrading to any version. NiFi is made so it can be upgraded easily. Just replace the the lib dir and deploy so you won't have to use such methods like 1&2